# Does Magento FPC treat Customer Groups differently?

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

Using M1 at the moment with Varnish for FPC, we always had an issue where Prices would get cached by the first Customer Group that would view a page.

For example, if a Wholesale Customer loaded a product, they would see their lower price. And then if a Retail Customer loaded the same page moments later, they would also see the lower price instead of theirs.

I know you can configure Varnish to account for that, but it was so un-user-friendly to get it right.

So I was wondering, if that will happen with the M2 FPC as well, or if Magento have already accounted for that?

Comment: probably you have to upgrade your M1 Varnish Cache extension, Turpentine?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, M2 has the different copy of content per Customer Groups.

[Plugin](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/App/Action/ContextPlugin.php) in from Customer Module add Customer Group Id to http context that responsible for generate cache id

Comment: how to generate cache by customer id not customer group